# Flask CRUD using SQLAlchemy, how can I load data column

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to load database value? using sql alchmey.
If I ask using get mehtod '127.0.0.1/api/v1/user/25/'

There is a value in database(id=5, username=jaeyeon, email=jae@naver.com)
I want to show this column.
but it can't. Where can I fix the code?
I don't know how parameter deliver.. Please help me :(

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:12345@localhost/catchat'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
class user(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        user_id = db.session.query(User.id == args['id']).filter(id)
        print user_id
        entry = [dict(id=user.id, username=user.username, email=user.email, password=user.password)]
        print entry
        return entry, 200
api.add_resource(user,'/api/v1/user/<int:id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set up your session a bit differently than I'm used to doing, so I'm not sure whether that makes any difference, but I can see some issues with the query you're making.  Try this instead:

```
user_id = db.session.query(User).filter_by(id = args['id']).one()
```

Assuming that `args['id']` is going to produce the proper value, then this will return the single matching row from `User`, and you can use dot notation to access the columns.  I see you seem to be a bit off when using the dot notation, remember that the values are now stored in `user_id` so you'd have to access them like this:

```
email = user_id.email
```

Comment: Thank you for reponse my question. I tried your code. but it can't there is a error showed me like this {
  "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}        this is my updated code :  user_id = db.session.query(User).filter_by(id = args['id'])

        entry = dict(id=user_id.id, username=user_id.username, email=user_id.email, password=user_id.password)
        print entry

Comment: Hm, in that case I think this problem is beyond my knowledge.  I'm sorry that I cannot do more to help.